# Localization issue in Flutter - AppLocalizations not found`

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization, flutter-localizations

I have added localization into my flutter app following flutter tutorial and few guidelines on internet. However, it seems not working.

I have done this in my `main.dart`

```
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'ProxymaNovaLight',
        ),
        localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const MainPage());
  }
}
```

Then I want to access one of the variable defined in my `app_en.arb` to display a text on my signin page.

The `app_en.arb` is as below:

```
{
    "signIn": "Sign In",
    "@signIn": {
        "description": "Text for SignIn button"
    }
}
```

So I did in signin.dart:

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:ui";
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

...

Widget emailTextField(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white70,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).signIn
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`AppLocalizations.of(context).signIn` remain underlined in red with the note: `Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)`

[image]

and below is a screenshot of my folders

[image]

I have added all required package in my `pubspec.yaml`.

Any idea why I cannot access my string >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your localized string isn’t a constant value so you have to remove const modifier before InputDecoration.

```
decoration: const InputDecoration
```

To

```
decoration: InputDecoration
```